# xwd/java.awt.Robot captures black windows (everything except unity2d shell is black)

Tags: screenshot, java, ubuntu-unity

Today, I ran into weird issue: `java.awt.Robot` captures black areas, instead of image content. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and OpenJDK6/7.

`java.awt.Robot` on Unix is supported by the `sun.awt.X11.XRobotPeer`,
which, following the [corresponding OpenJDK sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/07c1c59df4ef/src/solaris/native/sun/awt/awt_Robot.c), uses image grabbing functions similar to those, used by `xwd` utililty (lines 92-162).

So, I ran the following command:

```
xwd -root -out test.screen.root.xwd
```

and then opened this file with gimp. Here's what I get:

[image]

Then I tried:

```
xwd -root | xwdtopnm | pnmtopng > Screenshot.root.png
```

And I got the following result:
Console output:

```
xwdtopnm: writing PPM file
libpng warning: Invalid sBIT depth specified
```

And the image itself:
[image]

What can cause this? How can I fix it?

Comment: I would try your code on Oracle's official JDK, and if that doesn't work then try it on Windows on Oracle's official JDK. If either of those work with your code, then file a bug report. Either against openJDK or an official one. If none of those work with your code, then fix your code.

Comment: I tried that on OpenJDK6/7 and OracleJDK6/7. This is Ubuntu-linux only issue. Robot works as expected on Windows.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the only way to fix this is to use your own native implementation of screen shotting.

Here's the detailed description of the problem at the launchpad from unity devs: [launchpad conversation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/1081674).

The problem is in the way unity-2d draws itself and in the use of XShaping.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. Apparently, it is linked to `xwdtopnm` not handling well the color depth of your screen - causing the resulting png file to be corrupted.

An alternative solution is to use the `import` command from the `imagemagick` package to take the screenshot.

So you can just replace:

```sh
xwd -root | xwdtopnm | pnmtopng > Screenshot.root.png
```

with:

```sh
import -window root Screenshot.root.png
```

---

NB: if it is not installed, you can get `imagemagick` on Ubuntu with the following command:

```sh
sudo apt install imagemagick
```